# How to share a video from stored in raw folder of my app - Android studio

Tags: android, raw

I want to share a video that is stored inside the raw folder of my Android app. I saved this video file while developing my app. Now I want to share this by clicking a button on WhatsApp. How can I do this? Till now I can share video files by selecting from the gallery -

```
private void selectVideo(){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {

            Uri  uri  = data.getData();

            phone = "+91xxxxxxxx";

            Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            videoshare.setType("video/*");
            videoshare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  uri);

            startActivity(videoshare);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why you post irrelevant code? You know that all you need is to get uri which points to the resource in raw folder - and such question was already askead here ? (if it doesn't work then you may copy resource to private storage and share via FileProvider) Where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the file from raw resource to device storage and then use FileProvider to serve your file.

You could also use your own 'file'provider or RawProvider (extend ContentProvider) to serve the file directly from raw resource.

There are examples on internet for an AssetsProvider which serves directly files from assets.